# If my heart keeps pounding for one hour, will this help aid weight loss?

Tags: weight-loss, weights, heart-rate

The question is simple and clear, if my heart pounds graciously for one hour, will this help aid weight loss in any way?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "pounds graciously for one hour", but, if your heart rate does not return to whatever is considered normal for you within a short amount of time after training, I'd be a bit concerned.

Answer (score 1):

**If my heart keeps pounding graciously for one hour, will this help aid weight loss in any way?**

**No**. Weight loss occurs when you are in a **caloric deficit** (eat less than you usually do)